# Salesforce Administrator Certification Maintenance Spring 22 Problem

Tags: certification

I am having a problem with completing my Salesforce Administrator Certification Maintenance Spring 22 Task Restriction Rule Challenge.

When I click the "Launch" button to complete the Salesforce Administrator Certification Maintenance Challenge, I clicked on the "Setup" icon, then click on the Object Manager tab and then enter the term "Task" in the Quick Find field.

The Task Profile that opens up does not show a "Restriction Rules" menu option as shown in the attached screenshot.

Without a "Restriction Rules" menu option available, I cannot complete the Salesforce Administrator Certification Maintenance Challenge. I am now stuck.

How do you recommend that I resolve this problem as there is no "Restriction Rules" menu option available to complete the Salesforce Administrator Certification Maintenance Challenge?

John

Comment: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help is probably the better venue for questions like this.